# Best way to score pair differences

Tags: sampling, standard-deviation, group-differences

I'm fairly clueless how to accomplish my goal here...

Firstly a bit of back story: I have about 10 technicians, and they each make sets of concrete samples in the field. Each sample has 2 x 28 day results and we use the pair MPA differences to see if they are doing a good job (they should be as close to 0 difference as possible)

**Example table of calculated pair differences**

```
SET #   TECH    DIFFERENCE
1       A       1
2       A       1.5
3       A       1.5
4       B       1
5       B       1
6       C       0.5
```

Each tech could do between 1 and 500 sets a month.

I'm wondering how do I score this fairly? Using the average hardly seems fair for my technicians doing 500 sets a month compared to others doing maybe 10.

Anyway I'm hoping to get some help here as this is so far out of my field its not even funny!